# Временные таблицы и работа с ними

Tags: php, sql

```
$query2="CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '".$territory."' SELECT ter_name,ter_address,ter_type_id,ter_level,ter_mask,reg_id FROM t_koatuu_tree where reg_id  = ".$territory." AND t_koatuu_tree.ter_type_id BETWEEN 2 and 3";

    $db->query($query2);

    $query ="SELECT * FROM '".$territory."'";

    echo 'temp'.$query."<br>".'not temp'.$query2."<br>";


    $result = $db->query($query);
```

Запрос идет, но временная таблица не создается.

Как правильно было работать с временной таблицей?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: во-первых у тебя нет точки с запятой после первого запроса. что крайне важно. во-вторых важно знать каким расширением для работы с БД пользуешься. например для mysqli есть [mysqli_multi_query](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Comment: Пользую mysqli_query

Comment: ну вот используй  mysqli_multi_query

Comment: Итак временная таблица содалось мульти запрос прошел успешно но эффект от этого стал хуже, дольше все происходит. Что делать то ?? Естественно временная таблица должна была ускорить дело( А ее вообще блин не видно (

Comment: А много запросов по временной таблице? Если только один или на каждый запрос создается временная таблица, то смысла в этом нет.

Comment: дело в том что во в таблице записей 30700, а во временной таблице 27. Должен быть смысл от временной таблици .

Comment: я просто не могу найти нормального примера для тернарного оператора или вообще как сделать выбор между запросами при старте странички

Answer (score 1):

> Запрос идет, но временная таблица не создается.

Запрос [`CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-select.html) не умеет создавать временные таблицы и не допускает модификатора `IF NOT EXISTS`.

Если Вам необходима строго `TEMPORARY TABLE` - придётся, как в обсуждении вопроса написал **Алексей Шиманский**, первым запросом (`CREATE`) создавать, вторым (`INSERT`) наполнять.

Если можно обойтись статической таблицей (использование БД строго однопользовательское или не влом создавать и удалять таблицы с уникальными именами для каждого подключения) - тогда можете смело использовать `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`.

**ВАЖНОЕ ЗАМЕЧАНИЕ.** И в первом, и во втором случае таблица будет создана (если не указать иначе) на дефолтном движке,  почти наверняка это `InnoDB` - так что если не хочется попусту дёргать жёсткий диск (а судя по описанию, это так), укажите явно использование движка `Engine=MEMORY`. Тогда на диск будет записана только структура таблицы, а данные останутся в памяти, не трогая диск. 27 записей - это достаточно компактно, чтобы не задумываться об излишнем расходе памяти.

**UPDATE:** Если принято решение создавать временную таблицу, то самое разумное - вспомнить, что она локальна для соединения, сессии. Т.е. если она вдруг существует - её можно удалить, и никому другому это не помешает (с оговорками, конечно, помешать можно - но только себе самому). А потому ИМХО наиболее разумно поступить так:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `temptable`;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `temptable` (<table definition>) ENGINE = MEMORY;
INSERT INTO `temptable` SELECT <fieldset> FROM `sourcetablename`;
```

А уж выполнить это одним мультизапросом или тремя отдельными - решайте сами.

Comment: Запрос CREATE TABLE ... SELECT не умеет создавать временные таблицы и не допускает модификатора IF NOT EXISTS.

Умеет умеет. Я даже слелал скрин шот что бы вам показать но не знаю ка кхалить фотку в коменты.

Comment: `TEMPORARY` Документация ни полслова не говорит о создании временных таблиц таким типом запроса. Наличие недокументированной способности выполнить запрос может запросто оказаться местом для раскладывания грабель. Но если хотите - пользуйтесь.

Comment: `IF NOT EXISTS` Вот тут документация чётко говорит, что будет. Если таблица не существует - она создастся. Ну как бы и нормально, модификатор не потребовался. А вот если она существует, то единственным следствием наличия модификатора будет то, что данные в ней не изменятся (ну это правильно), а вместо строгого `ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table '%s' already exists` генерируется более мягкое `Note (Code 1050): Table '%s' already exists`. Ну не знаю, насколько это офигеть как важно - заменить ошибку на предупреждение...

Comment: Если знаете как залить фотку могу залить запрос, Я не возражаю против вашего предложения я просто не пойму как мне создать времеенную таблицу в память, и проверять PHP создана ли временная таблица, если создана то выбрать из временной таблици свои данные.

Comment: Дополнил ответ. *как залить фотку* - см. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5672/229437

Comment: [ссылка](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMTww.png)